# how to get array and session variable to go back to being blank after browser is refreshed?

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have a problem where everytime I refresh the browser, I want the array which contians a $_SESSION variable to go back to being blank. At moment lets say I uploaded 2 files and then refresh browser, when I upload another file, it shows the name of the previous files uploaded when it shouldn't. How can I get the array and session variable to go back to being blank if browser is refreshed?

Below is code:

```
  function stopImageUpload(success){

          var imageNameArray = new Array();
// WHEN PAGE IS REFRESH, ARRAY SHOULD GO BACK TO BEING BLANK

 imageNameArray = <?php echo json_encode(isset($_FILES ['fileImage']['name']) ? $_FILES ['fileImage']['name'] : null); ?>;
//RETRIEVES THE SESSION VARIABLE FROM THE PHP SCRIPT OF THE FILE NAMES WHICH HAVE BEEN UPLOADED

          var result = '';



          if (success == 1){
             result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';

                for(var i=0;i<imageNameArray.length;i++)  //LOOP THROUGH ALL UPLOADED FILE NAMES
        {
             $('.listImage').append(imageNameArray[i]+ '<br/>');//APPEND FILE NAME

         }

          }
          else {
             result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
          }

    return true;

    }
```

Below is the php script where it uploads a file which is on another page from the javascript function above:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $result = 0;
    $errors = array ();
    $dirImage = "ImageFiles/";


if (isset ( $_FILES ['fileImage'] ) && $_FILES ["fileImage"] ["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

$fileName = $_FILES ['fileImage'] ['name'];

$fileExt = pathinfo ( $fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
$fileExt = strtolower ( $fileExt );


$fileDst = $dirImage . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;

        if (count ( $errors ) == 0) {
            if (move_uploaded_file ( $fileTemp, $fileDst )) {
                $result = 1;


            }
        }

    }

    ?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result;?>);</script>
```

Comment: Why would you store the name of the file that's being uploaded in $_SESSION var in the first place? $_SESSION is meant to be used for data that *needs* to be persistent during that session.

Comment: So the user can see the name of the file they have uploaded.

Comment: Just show it to them using $_FILES['fileImage']['name']; You don't need to store it in Session

Comment: Oh, ok i will try it this way and see what happens :)

Comment: I have tried what you have said by using $_FILES['fileImage']['name']; rather than storing it in a session but it keeps coming up with an error stating imageNameArray is null. Why do you think error is appearing?

Comment: I updated code in question so you can see whole code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I agree with the comment of @Reza Sanaie, you can solve your particular problem by unsetting the variable after a successful upload:

```
     if (success == 1)
     {
         result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';

         for(var i=0;i<imageNameArray.length;i++)  //LOOP THROUGH ALL UPLOADED FILE NAMES
         {
             $('.listImage').append(imageNameArray[i]+ '<br/>');//APPEND FILE NAME

         }

         $_SESSION ['fileImage'] = NULL; // or use unset()
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

After the form is submitted and your PHP has done its work you need to do a 303 redirect to the page you wish to display. Then when a user refreshes the page you won't a second form submission.

For example:

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], true, 303);
```

Comment: It goes in your PHP and is used *after* it has done whatever work it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just do your error checking in PHP, and pass an array to your HTML page to display the list of uploaded files in the page. You don't need javascript.

Have a look at [How to upload files in PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Comment: The files do upload, that is not the problem, I just want the file names which are stored in the server when files are uploaded to be appended onto the screen using javascript.

Comment: Just create an array of the name of the files that were uploaded and pass them to HTML. Does it have to be done using Javascript?